# Load Content Using AJAX/jQuery

Tags: jquery

See http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/poker-players.html - Im trying to load three contents on this page using AJAX/jQuery and it will not load the contents (eventually, I would want to load each content using JSON callings), but first I want to see if this works before I go deeper using JSON. Please let me know If this is not the best way to load the content using AJAX/jQuery - appreciate it.

HTML

```
<article class="span3">
  <ul class="list-1">
    <li class="navlinks" id="pokerplayers"><a href="#pokerplayers">EDPS Poker Players </a></li>
    <li class="navlinks" id="playerofthemonth"><a href="#playerofthemonth">Players of the Month</a></li>
    <li class="navlinks" id="playeroftheyear"><a href="#playeroftheyear">Players of the Year </a></li>
 </ul>
</article>
<article class="span9">
 <div id="content">
    Contents to load...
 </div>
</article>
```

Javascript (content.js)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pokerplayers").click(function(e){
var page = $(this).attr('href, word: hash');
e.preventDefault(); 
$("#content").load("content.html #pokerplayers");
$(this).hide().fadeIn("slow");
});
$("#playerofthemonth").click(function(e){ 
var page = $(this).attr('href, word: hash');
e.preventDefault(); 
$("#content").load("content.html #playerofthemonth");
$(this).hide().fadeIn("slow");
});
$("#playeroftheyear").click(function(e){
var page = $(this).attr('href, word: hash'); 
e.preventDefault(); 
$("#content").load("content.html #playeroftheyear");
$(this).hide().fadeIn("slow");
});
});
```

content.html

```
<div id="pokerplayers">
   <p class="content-text">Poker Players</p>
</div>
<div id="playerofthemonth">
   <p class="content-text">Player of the Month</p>
</div>
<div id="playeroftheyear">
   <p class="content-text">Player of the Year</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works for me, are u running it by opening the file up or using a server? It didn't work when running it like this:

```
file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/stackoverflow/index.html
```

but when I uploaded it to my server it worked just fine, look [here](http://consultingfox.com/stackoverflow/)

Comment: Yeah, it works now, but the left nav disappears after clicking one of the links. It should load to the content id div. What went wrong?

Comment: $(this).hide().fadeIn("slow"); with that line you are telling it to dissapear, just comment it out or remove it.

Comment: I removed them and the left nav still disappeared.

Comment: there must be something else, that I don't know about..If you view source code on the site I submitted you can see what I'm doing and what I've taken out.  Also you don't need e.preventDefault since you are not capturing the "a" click but the "li"..